# JSONP is not returning results on second call on an ASP.MVC & JQuery solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsonp

I have implemented the solution on this link to my project to have jsonp capabilities:
http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/entry-EnablingJSONPcallsonASPNETMVC.aspx

It is working like a charm on first calls but on second call it is not responding?

Do you have any idea?

My json call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '../../askjson',
    data: { name_startsWith: name },
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) { }
});
```

and controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
[JsonpFilter]
public JsonResult askjson(string name_startsWith)
{

    // do stuff

    return Json(resultView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: "not responding" does not provide a lot of information about your problem.
Is your cache directive effective ? (You can check this with fiddler / firebug => network. Jquery should append a random parameter to the qs).
Does your second call gets to the server ? (you can check this with debugger or logger).
Does your problem comes from you onsuccess function introducing inconsistency in you html (duplicate ids...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys.

I've traced the error and it was a 400 indicating that: request is over the allowed setting defined at `MaxQueryStringLength`.

So I've added the following to my web.config under `<system.web>`

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
```

I also did same to `<system.webServer>` by:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151"  />
```

my problem has gone!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Gorkem U can check this code project solution on jsonp

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223572/Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-service-using-Jquery-Java